# .Net application on Android OS

Tags: android, monodroid

I am Database Administrator, but now I need to know something about android applications.

I need to run an existing .Net application in Android Operating System, while surfing on the internet I came to know that, I can use MonoDroid to build and run my application on Androids Operating System.

I am new to this Android and MonoDroid applications, so 
**My questions:**

- Is it possible to run an existing .Net application on Android without modification?
- If not, is there a known set of changes necessary to make a .NET application run on Android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't run an existing .NET application as is. You need to implement the necessary functionality to fit in with the ecosystem, namely having an activity. In addition to this, you need to code to the Android user interface.

Monodroid will not run a WinForms application, or any other type of .NET application without modification.

The power comes from being able to leverage existing investments in non-GUI classes. If you develop your applications in a structured, componentized manner, you should be able to leverage large portions of your existing code.

For a list of unsupported BCL classes, see the [Mono status page](http://www.go-mono.com/status/).

Comment: You're welcome. Mono is a great platform. The ability to use the same code across multiple platforms is great.

Answer (score -1):

You really can't effectively use .NET on the Android platform at this point. The tools, such as Monodroid, are too limited for many uses. Microsoft also has good reason to push their own mobile platform.

Right now, the easiest way to handle this is to use a web based app with a responsive front end design that will adapt to smartphone, tablet and laptop/desktop users. This approach will allow your app to operate on more devices with minimal special coding. If your user base allows the use of HTML 5 it makes designing a powerful front end even easier.

Another possible approach is to use an app builder/framework to develop the app UI for mobile platforms and have them talk to a .NET based web service. Of course, the app won't be .NET but if you want an app and not a website and don't have the time to learn all the ins and outs of developing on Android and Apple, using an app builder might be the fastest method to use.

Comment: Sorry I completely disagree with you. I designed and developed a POS application with a distributed architecture running on Android in a very short period of time. How is Monodroid limited?

Comment: in response to your deleted comment, you've obviously provided some good advice on a variety of sites (hence your reputation) however from your answer I would suggest that you have not used Monodroid. Furthermore, I'd be interested in hearing more about how you feel Monodroid is limited.